# Style four inputs to look like one

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style four input controls to looks like the below image any help to get me started would be great

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Chrome, open dev tools (F12), navigate to the 'Elements' tab, select the 'inspect element' tool on the top left (shortcut: cmd+shift+C) and hover over and then click on the input controls.

This will display the styling that goes in to creating that element, and you can try your hand at replicating it from there.